# Linear Algebra: Inverting an induced operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, exterior-algebra, quantum-field-theory

**Question**: Given an invertible linear map $U:V\to V$, consider the induced map $\tilde{U}:\Lambda^k(V)\to \Lambda^k(V)$ given by
$$\tilde{U}(v_1\wedge \cdots\wedge v_k):=\sum_{j=1}^kv_1\wedge \cdots \wedge Uv_j\wedge \cdots\wedge v_k.$$
Is there a nice formula for $\tilde{U}^{-1}$ in terms of $U^{-1}$?

**Context**:  in quantum field theory, such a formula would allow one to solve for a many-electron Green's function in terms of a single-electron Green's function.

Comment: In general $\tilde U$ does not have to be invertible, even if $U$ is. Take for example $V=\mathbb R^n$ and $Ue_i=e_{i+1}$ for $i<n$ and $Ue_n=e_1$. This is evidently invertible, but the induced action on $\Lambda^n(\mathbb R^n)$ kills $e_1\wedge\dots\wedge e_n$ and hence is the zero map. The extension to $\Lambda^k$ that you use is appropriate for Lie algebra actions (so you would use these on infinitesimal generators). To extend Lie group actions one uses ${\hat U}(v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k)=Uv_1\wedge\dots\wedge Uv_k$ and for this you get $\widehat{U^{-1}}=\hat U^{-1}$.

Comment: I understand this, but for some reason many-body theory is still consistent. Perhaps it has to do with the case that $V$ is infinite-dimensional? I'll get back to this later, after a proper calculation.